# Is there a way to reuse <c:url> logic inside my custom JSP tag?

Tags: java, jstl, jsp-tags, code-reuse

So I've got this custom JSP tag I've been working on. I now need to do pretty much what `<c:url>` will do in my tag plus my custom logic.

Is there a way to just re-use `<c:url>` logic? Inheritance doesn't look like an option since `<c:url>` will set/print its own `setAttributes` on the `pageContext` that I don't want. And overriding that method will means code it again.

Any ideas?

Comment: My approach would depend on what the nature of the custom logic is--can you just make a JSP-based tag? Otherwise, there's not a *whole* lot to `c:url`.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks, well the customs tag are designed to print the typical links to pages (<<first, <prev, 1 2 3... next> last>>) in a search result page. So to code again the <c:url><c:param> seems a overkill, since core jstl do it, and do it *very well*. (Adds the web context, deals with url encoding, etc...) future releases of <c:url> might improve as well my tag.

Comment: Oh. I'd just use an existing pagination solution, I guess.

Comment: Even the old [jsptags](http://jsptags.com/tags/navigation/pager/) library is okay, [displaytag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/) is used by a lot of people. I'd just poke around; it's a solved problem.

Comment: Thanks that's great information. seems that [Pager TL](http://jsptags.com/tags/navigation/pager/index.jsp) will be useful

Answer (score 0):

[Displaytag](http://www.displaytag.org/) is a good solution to this as Dave pointed out, it has a lot of built in functionality making it a lot more easier, or else you could manually create page links(this is what I would do, its not complicated and there are plenty of samples around.)